# How to revert changes in angular 1 Ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am trying to revert the value of input box when user clicks *Cancel* button. What I am doing wrong here? Here *show* button will backup the value of a in 'temp' variable and if the user cancels the input with the help of *revert* button it should reflect original values.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name={}
    var temp=""
    $scope.name.a = {"person":"Shah"};
    $scope.editOn = false
    $scope.abc= function(){
        $scope.editOn= true
        temp=$scope.name.a
    }
    $scope.cde= function(){
        $scope.name.a =  temp
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"><br>
{{name.a.person}}  <br>
Name: <input ng-model="name.a.person" ng-show="editOn">
<button ng-click="abc()">show</button>
<button ng-click="cde()">revert</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two errors,

1. You are modifying temp variable everytime input value changes, so temp doesn't store the initial value anymore.
2. temp and name.a point to same object, they have same reference. So you'll have to copy the object so that temp and name.a have reference to different objects.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name={}
    var temp=""
    $scope.name.a = {"person":"Shah"};
    $scope.editOn = false
    temp=angular.copy($scope.name.a)
    $scope.abc= function(){
      $scope.editOn= true
    }
    $scope.cde= function(){
      $scope.name.a =  temp
      console.log(temp)
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"><br>
{{name.a.person}}  <br>
Name: <input ng-model="name.a.person" ng-show="editOn">
<button ng-click="abc()">show</button>
<button ng-click="cde()">revert</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining and introducing angular.copy thing into my life :). It totally works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `ng-change` and storing a string and not an object in your `temp` variable. See snippet below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name={}
$scope.changeName = () => {
    $scope.name.a.person = $scope.inputModel;
}
var temp=""
    $scope.name.a = {"person":"Shah"};
    $scope.editOn = false
    $scope.abc= function(){
         $scope.editOn= true
         temp = $scope.name.a.person
         $scope.inputModel = temp;
    }
    $scope.cde = function(){
         $scope.inputModel =  temp
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"><br>
{{name.a.person}}  <br>
Name: <input ng-change="changeName()" ng-model="inputModel" ng-show="editOn">
<button ng-click="abc()">show</button>
<button ng-click="cde()">revert</button>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```